# How to write a class that uses other classes but needs the same functionality - should I just wrap around the methods?

Tags: design, c++, solid, design-principles

I want to create a class ProcessHandler for Windows that pretty much uses the WINAPI.

The class `ProcessHandler` should be able to scan memory, emulate keyboard and mouse, needs some DLLInjector, some hooking, and provides some process information. Since I want to use some design principles, I think I should split every part into their own classes (class `MemoryScanner` for example) and then let `ProcessHandler` just use the class.

[image]

Do I then just redefine (wrap around) the `ArrayOfByte` method of `ProcessHandler` like that

```
ArrayOfByteScan(){
    return memoryscanner.ArrayOfByteScan()
}
```

Is this a valid approach? And considered good design?

I also dont like that every class (if I do it like that) has its own `HANDLE` datatype. For example, the class `MemoryScanner` and `DLLInjector` will need it. Is there also a different approach for that?

I have never applied any design patterns/principles and my usual approach would just be writing every method inside `ProcessHandler`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The question is how to make a single ProcessHandler to work with several and different *Process*. Right?

Comment: @Laiv no how to Design Code so i Can Split up one big class into small classes and then Reuse all classes inside the big class so they have all the functionalitys of the small classes. I think the answers with Adapter pattern and Dependency injection are the answer to my Problem but i still had no time to try it out tho (sry for Bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you described it, your `ProcessHandler` will be a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to all the other classes you mentioned like `MemoryScanner`, `KeyboardEmulator` etc., which provide "parts" of the containing `ProcessHandler` object. Splitting up the different responsibility to different classes is fine, that is a perfect example of the [single responsibility priciple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You know that you have done the split-up correctly when you can develop unit tests for each of the "parts" of the `ProcessHandler` and test it in isolation.

For avoiding the need for a duplicate process handle, for the shown example it is probably most simple to make the handle a parameter of the called methods and pass it from the `ProcessHandler` object to the aggregate objects, like

```
 ArrayOfByteScan(){
    return memoryscanner.ArrayOfByteScan(handle)
 }
```

For more complex scenarios, one could create an interface / abstract base class `IHandlerContainer` with a virtual method `GetHandler`, and inject a pointer to an `IHandlerContainer` into each of the parts at construction time. Then,  `ProcessHandler` can be derived from that interface, and let the `ProcessHandler` constructor look roughly like

```
 ProcessHandler::ProcessHandler()
  :memoryscanner(this), keyboardEmulator(this)
 { ... 
 }
```

That will give an object like `memoryscanner` access to the handle inside `ProcessHandler` without creating a cyclic dependency between those two classes.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for pointing me to the right directions, didnt asked for more <3

Comment: Okay after further reading/coding and checking what adapter,decorator and facade pattern is this can safely be the accepted answer, thanks so much again